# Get the name that a person logged on to the computer with

Tags: php, javascript

I was wondering if it was possible to get the username of the person who had logged on to the computer in php or javascript. For example, if I get on my laptop, log in to the computer, and go to the website, I would want it to show the name I logged in with.

Is there any way to do this, or is it impossible

Comment: Do you mean the username of the website you logged in to, or the username of your Windows/Mac/Linux name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible with PHP or Javascript.

You can look at the headers sent to the server to see what data is sent ([getallheaders](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)).

As others suggest you can use plugins that integrate more tightly with the host computer to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, you will have to use a PHP webserver plugin like active directory.  But the user will have to authenticate with your site, you cannot just 'pull it'

**LDAP example:**
[Authenticating in PHP using LDAP through Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171519/authenticating-in-php-using-ldap-through-active-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible if you have the Apache NTLM module. But you would have to be able to install it on your server. So if it is a hosted box, probably not going to work. Downside, I think it only works with IE.

> NTLM is an authentication protocol used by Microsoft Internet
>   Informations Server(tm) and Microsoft Internet Explorer(tm). While it
>   is not really secure, it offers background authentication (the
>   workstation logon credentials of users are passed through to the web
>   server). This feature is widely used in intranets based on these
>   Microsoft products.

http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side scripting engine and it knows nothing about the client except for what browser sends to the server, but username isn't there.

Same with JavaScript - this one operates client-side, but sharing username with webpages could be a serious security flaw. Websites should be kept away from any user-sensitive data.

And finally, some systems may not implement any user profiles (like mobile phones and smartphones). What would be sent then?

Answer (score 0):

if it is just the login (user ID):

```html
<?php echo filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'LOGON_USER'); ?>
```

which is the same as

```html
<?php echo $_SERVER['LOGON_USER']; ?>
```

you also could use

```html
<?php

foreach ($_SERVER as $var => $value){
    
    echo "$var => $value<br />";
    
}

?>
```

to show all the possible values for the superglobal $_SERVER avaible in your server or localhost.