# How do I disallow anonymous ldap login?

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I have the following:

```
class LDAPConnection {

    private $ldapServers = array(
        "ldap://serv1", "ldap://serv2"
    );
    private $ldapUsername = "DOMAIN\\%s";

    function login($username, $password)    {
        $user = sprintf($this->ldapUsername, $username);
        // Make sure password is not empty (http://stackoverflow.com/a/172042/561731)
        if(!empty($password))   {
            foreach($this->ldapServers as $server)  {
                try {
                    $ldap = \ldap_connect($server);
                    \ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
                    if($bind = \ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $password))  {
                        // log them in
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch(\ErrorException $e)   {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see I first make sure that the `$password` is not empty then I attempt the ldap connection, because if I do not do that, then ldap assumes that I want to do an anonymous connection and returns `true`.

How do I prevent that? Is my only option like I did above and I have to check to **make sure** that the password isn't empty? Or is there a better way?

Comment: What's wrong with checking that `$password` isn't empty? Seems like pretty basic validation. Just throw an exception.

Comment: @ceejayoz it seems like an extra thing that might not be needed if there was some `ldap_*` function to do it for you.

Comment: I doubt there's an `ldap_*` function to do it when it's a simple `if($password)`... especially as binding w/o password is technically legit.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling anonymous login shouldn't be done at your application layer.  It should be done at the actual LDAP server itself.

Prohibiting anonymous login at your application layer to me seems like a band-aid because anyone can always use any LDAP client to log into your LDAP server if anonymous login is enabled on the server itself.

Comment: It absolutely IS a band-aid. You might think all organizations give the keys to the kingdom to their developers. If so, you are very wrong. People like me - who work in a large bureaucratic institution - have to code workarounds like this all the frikkin' time. Getting the smallest change done can take months, if at all.