# Connect laravel with Active Directory

Tags: laravel

i want to connect my laravel app with  Active Directory to get student data like email and password and with this information the student can login in the laravel app without registerd , note i want also mysql run to record a new user , Summary what i want from Active Directory is data student and student can login with this data if user signup the information record in mysql i will try with LdapRecord v2 but he save a new record in active directory i don`t want that i want to save in msql not in Active Directory
thanks.

i want to connect my laravel app with  Active Directory

Comment: just curious.. what have you [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/172042)?